# How can I record detailed user metrics for a web application?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, user-experience, metrics

I'm not sure if "user metrics" is necessarily the right term to use but essentially I am interested in gathering certain kinds of data about my users as they browse my site, probably just during a private beta.

An example of the kind of thing I am interested in, albeit not applied to a web application, is the [click tracking](https://heatmap.mozillalabs.com/mozmetrics/) employed by Mozilla using Test Pilot. This allowed them to determine, for example, which UI elements were most important to their users.

Some examples of the things I would like to record:

- the number of clicks on different UI elements
- the time it takes for users to complete certain tasks like fill in forms
- the number of times a user submits a form with invalid data and, if they do, what fields are invalid and how they are invalid

Now I could, of course, code something like this from scratch but I was wondering if there existed already some sort of library to do this for me. I am using both Rails and jQuery so whatever I use must be compatible, and preferably based upon those frameworks.

Unfortunately, having no experience or knowledge of this sort of thing, I have been able to find anything through Google but the Firefox example above comes closest to the type of thing I want to achieve. I've also checked various Rails and jQuery sites but either there is nothing out there or I am lacking the correct terminology.

Note: I am already aware of A/B testing and this is the closest kind of testing I can find to what I have in mind but is obviously very different still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend Google Analytics.

We do this kind of thing a lot at work, and GA's Event Tracking is pretty much perfect for it. This is how you use it:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Value']);
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Does Google Analytics Event Tracking do what you want?

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/product.html), which you probably know about already.

Also have used [Web Trends](http://www.webtrends.com/Products/Analytics/Web), which can dive in as deep as you could possibly need.